# How to convert Angular locale date to proper date format for API to consume?

Tags: angular, date, querystringparameter, date-pipe

I am using two-way binding in my template driven form:

ts:

```
searchLeaveApplication: any = {};
```

html:

```
<mat-form-field class="searchInputs">
  <input
    matInput
    [matDatepicker]="searchStartDate"
    [(ngModel)]="this.searchLeaveApplication.startDate"
    name="startDate"
  />
  <mat-datepicker-toggle
    matSuffix
    [for]="searchStartDate"
  ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #searchStartDate></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

However I am getting this as the date:
[image]

Which is not acceptable as a date format for the API (.Net core). How can I change to format to the proper date format? I suppose I am not able to use date pipes in two-way bindings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always import Angular's [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe), or [FormatDate](https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate) into your component.ts, and convert `searchLeaveApplication.startDate` to the required datetime format that is accepted by .Net core. The full list of pre-defined options and custom formats can be found [here](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#usage-notes).

1) If you are intending to use `DatePipe`, you may do the following below.

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {   

constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

  saveData() {
    const searchStartDateString = this.datePipe.transform(this.searchLeaveApplication.startDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    // handle the rest
  }
}
```

Do not forget to add DatePipe to your providers in your module.

```
providers: [DatePipe]
```

2) Alternatively, you may want to use `formatDate`:

```
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';

export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string) {}

  saveData() {
    const searchStartDateString = formatDate(this.searchLeaveApplication.startDate, 'MM-yyyy', this.locale);
    // handle the rest
  }
}
```